# Application in Vista OS, but few threads are not active and running

Tags: windows-vista

I have my app, running one on XP & one on Vista OS.
But there is a difference in thread count. 
XP - 18 , Vista -14 threads.
Few threads are not started in my application which is running in Vista OS. So my application in Vista is not fully functioning. Any setting to be done?. 
I have switched off the UAC in Vista.

Sounds crazy but true..

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are observing other symptoms of failure, your application is probably working normally.  When used by an application, various Windows subsystems will start threads of their own within the application's process.  COM, for example, starts and stops its RPC worker threads at will.  No guarantee is made that the number of such threads will remain constant within a single application instance, let alone from one version of Windows to the next.

Comment: Yes, i agree..
few functionality particular to few RPC callbacks are not working in my application , which is running in Vista OS. that is the thing bothering.I'm afraid if i should do any setting for this application w.r.t Priority/Compatibility.....

Comment: I have updated one COM-based application to Windows Vista.  In general, I found that security settings which permitted the application to work on XP also permitted it to work on Vista.

The single point on which I had to adapt the application was that an out-of-process COM server is started in session 0, which is (normally) an interactive session on XP, but which is never an interactive session on Vista.  Therefore I had to move some user interaction to a helper program that runs in the user's session.